# Changing saved reflectance panel values in Pix4D

Tags: aerial-photography, photogrammetry, reflectance, pix4d

We have a Micasense rig for multispectral imagery, and when my coworker set up my Pix4D account & did a test run he used the wrong reflectance values for our calibration panel. Pix4D saves those values to use any time you use that panel (it can read the QR code), which means it saved the wrong ones.

Is there any way to replace those values, or am I stuck changing them manually every time I process multispec data?

---

I emailed Pix4D & was told this is, in fact, impossible--presumably short of getting a new license & clean install, which may have to happen. (We're getting a new computer for this, anyway.)

From the website:

> The reflectance value entered manually will be saved in the software
> and automatically reused if another project is created in the future
> with the same camera and calibration target.

And from Pix4D Support:

> There is no way to save the
> panel reflectance factor. Usually, PIX4Dmapper should automatically
> use the reflectance factor value for the panel that is in our database
> such as one from the Micasense.    The best practise is to verify the
> reflectance panel and the marking of the reflectance panel before
> processing the project to make sure everything is good.

I am a bit suspicious that the HelpDesk is just unfamiliar enough with the software that there MIGHT be a workaround, but unless someone else has fixed this before I think I'm stuck with fixing the incorrect values manually, every time.

A reminder to me to be absolutely sure we're using the right data, even if I'm not the one entering it!